# crear reportes en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Espero me puedan apoyar, requiero generar reportes en php que se muestren en una tabla, tengo una base de datos donde tengo los registros para hacer los reportes.

Esta es mu tabla de mysql donde tengo los registros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como lo estoy generando es de la siguiente manera:

```html
    <?php $registros = $conn->query("SELECT numero_personal, nombre_empleado, empresa, cc_nomina, importe
     FROM portal_transparencia");
    $grupoAnterior = '';
    foreach ($registros as $key => $item) {
    $agrupador = $item["numero_personal"];
if($agrupador != $grupoAnterior) {
<table border = "1"  >
        <thead>
            <tr>        
            <td style="background-color:white;" colspan="2">
                
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">             
                    <br>
                    No. Empleado: $item[numero_personal]
                    <br>
                    Nombre: $item[nombre_empleado]
                    <br>
                    Empresa: $item[empresa]
                    
                </div>          
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>    
            <td style="background-color:white; ">           
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    
                    <br>
                    Persepciones:
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:white;">
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    
                    <br>
                    Deducciones:
                </div>      
            </td>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
$grupoAnterior = $item["numero_personal"];
}elseif($agrupador == $grupoAnterior){

<table border = "1"  >
        <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    $item[cc_nomina] - $item[importe] <br>
                    $item[numero_personal]
                </div>          
            </td>
            <td>            
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    $item[cc_nomina] - $item[importe] <br>
                    $item[numero_personal]
                    
                </div>              
            </td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                 <td>Total: 9878</td>
                 <td>Total: 7689</td>
           </tr>
</tfoot>

</table>
}
```

Lo que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con su respectivo total entre cada columna.

Alguna sugerencia de como puedo lograr este trabajo, ojala pudieran ayudarme u orientarme para lograr resolver este problema que me trae vuelto loco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De seguro hay errores de sintaxis solo es  una idea de como podrías hacerlo

```
 

    <?php $registros = $conn->query("SELECT numero_personal, nombre_empleado, empresa, 
 cc_nomina, importe
     FROM portal_transparencia");
    $grupoAnterior = '';
    $contador = 1;
    foreach ($registros as $key => $item) {
 $cantidad = $conn->query("SELECT Count(numero_personal) FROM portal_transparencia where 
 numero_personal = '$item["numero_personal' ");

    $agrupador = $item["numero_personal"];
if($agrupador != $grupoAnterior) {
<table border = "1"  >
        <thead>
            <tr>        
            <td style="background-color:white;" colspan="2">
                
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">             
                    <br>
                    No. Empleado: $item[numero_personal]
                    <br>
                    Nombre: $item[nombre_empleado]
                    <br>
                    Empresa: $item[empresa]
                    
                </div>          
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>    
            <td style="background-color:white; ">           
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    
                    <br>
                    Persepciones:
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:white;">
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    
                    <br>
                    Deducciones:
                </div>      
            </td>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
$grupoAnterior = $item["numero_personal"];
}elseif($agrupador == $grupoAnterior){

<table border = "1"  >
        <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    $item[cc_nomina] - $item[importe] <br>
                    $item[numero_personal]
                </div>          
            </td>
            <td>            
                <div style="font-size:8.5px; text-align:center; line-height:15px;">
                    $item[cc_nomina] - $item[importe] <br>
                    $item[numero_personal]
                    
                </div>              
            </td>
            </tr>
if($contador == $cantidad){
        <tfoot>
                <tr>
                     <td>Total: 9878</td>
                     <td>Total: 7689</td>
               </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
$contador= 0
}
       
    </tbody>
}
 $contador = $contador + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Gracias por la idea, le agregue un foreach en la parte del footer para que funcionara correctamente